# inotify does run twice

Tags: linux, unix, shell, script

I wanted to write a script that triggers some code when a file gets changed (meaning the content changes or the file gets overwritten by file with the same name) in a specific directory (or in a subdirectory). When running my code and changing a file it seems to run it twice every time. Is there something I am missing?

```
while true; do
   change=$(inotifywait -e close_write /home/bla)
   change=${change#/home/bla/ * }
   echo "$change"
done
```

Also it doesn't do anything when I change something in a subdirectory.

Comment: Take a look on this http://superuser.com/questions/1133642/traceing-the-moment-when-file-is-completely-copied-to-samba-share-with-inotify

Answer (score 0):

Ok, most probably you are running to monitors on the same directory, check your inotify list.
Secondly if you want to do something when a file is being copied to a directory do this

```
IN_MODIFY,IN_ONESHOT /direcotry sleep timeAmmountThatIsEnaugToCopyTheFile commands
```